# core data versioning on document based applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, structure, versioning

My application uses Core-data. Now, with the release of the new version I need to change the database structure. 
I know this is done via versioning, but all I have found, all tutorials are not for document based applications and at some point i get stuck. How can Versioning be implemented on a document based application, where the document is the database itself and can have any name?

Thanks

---Additional info----

what i would need to do is: open the application, hit the "open" button, select the NSManagedDocument from the filesystem. that is my database (can have any name) if on opening it detects that it is an old structure it should update its structure to the current one. (one column added)

Comment: Where did you get struck? Or, more precisely, where did you get stuck?

Comment: in all examples i found i had to indicate the name of the database, but since its a document based app and the database is a file, it can have any name. Also i have to add the persistent store options in the appdelegate.m file, but in a document based app i have only the document.m file. pasting the options code there does not work, i get a lot of errors. pretty green here. thanks

Comment: Sorry, your level is such that this site will not be able to help you. You have to understand what you are doing first. Most pragmatic advice for you: abandon NSManagedDocument and just follow the Core Data templates.

Comment: i appreciate your answer and that you took the time to write this. But my app is already written and for the way it is made it needs the Data to be stored in those files. and, i still need to implement this versioning, so maybe you can point me to the right direction. i am willing to learn, but as you said my level is very low.

Comment: Please show the code (by editing your question) where you the core data sqlite store to the NSManagedDocument.

Comment: I'm afraid i dont understand you. what i would need to do is: open the application, hit the "open" button, select the NSManagedDocument that is my database (can have any name) if on opening i see that it is an old version i update its structure. adding a Bounty to this question...

Comment: I expanded my answer to make it clear.

Comment: There's... no such class as `NSManagedDocument`.

Comment: sorry, i am a very newbie with this. i meant the file that i chose where my core data is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the fact that you are wrapping the SQLite store into an `NSManagedDocument` is irrelevant to the model versioning procedure.

Just proceed by adding the persistent store options in code and the new model version in Xcode.

When setting up your core data stack - i.e. after the document with the DB has been chosen - you have to add these options to the persistent store when creating the persistent store coordinator:

```
NSString * const NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption;
NSString * const NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption;
```

As the names of these options imply, it should work automatically from here. The actual call would look something like this:

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator 
   addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
   configuration:@"Default"
   URL:fileURL 
   options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption       : @(YES)}
   error:&error];
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. does this code need to be imlemented in the document.m file or in the appdelegate.m file? i suppose in the doucment.m since it has to be executed for each file that is eventually loaded.. right?

Comment: Right. If that is your setup - i.e. creating a new SQLite database for each new document, why not? The usual way is to completely hide the document and just use it in the app delegate to wrap around the sqlite database and have that store everything ("all documents"). But you seem to intend to do something else with your setup.

Comment: yes my application uses a database file. its meant to be like that because users can put those files on the usb stick and move it to the work pc for example. Will try and report back! thanks!

Comment: i might be too stupid, but i dont seem tobe able to make it work. i accept your answer so at least somebody gets th epoints.. thank you anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the points. Time allowing, I will try to make a sample project for demonstration and share with you.

Comment: that would be great! :)

Comment: hello, did you have a chance to look at this? thanks! sorry if i stress but i am stuck with the developement wihtout this.

Comment: Sorry - I am deep over my head with updating apps for iOS 7! Would an iOS sample work for you as well?

Comment: i hope so! dont know.. i think it should work if the migration is done the same way.. but are there document based apps in IOS?

Comment: No - I really did not get to it yet… I have something like this working on iOS, but it appears the setup is somewhat different on OS X.